# smsGateway.Me I AM GETTING THIS ERROR WHEN I WANT TO SEND SMS USING API

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

I want to send SMS using the `smsgateway.me` API, but I'm getting this response:

```
{"response":false,"status":0}
```

Here is my code:

```
include "smsGateway.php";
$smsGateway = new SmsGateway('xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxx');
$deviceID = xxxxx;
$number = '+92xxxxxxxxxx';
$message = 'Hello World!';
$options = [
    'send_at' => strtotime('+1 minutes'), // Send the message in 10 minutes
    'expires_at' => strtotime('+1 hour') // Cancel the message in 1 hour if the message is not yet sent
];

$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message, $deviceID, $options);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please verify that cURL is enabled in your host

Comment: If cURL wasn't enabled OP wouldn't be getting JSON back from the API.